# Keeping track of total number of runs of inner loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a nested function, simplified below. I would like to keep track of the total runs in the inner loop, in order those values might be used later on, when naming output files.

Here is my current, nested loop, which prints the column name, and the item in an enumerated class attribute, `self.vals`:

```
for n in df["col"]:

    for idx, item in enumerate(self.vals):

        print(n, item)

        print(str(idx))
```

There are 2 items in df column `col`, and 2 items in attribute `self.vals`. The inner loop index counts the 2 items in `self.vals`, giving (0, 1), and then resets before running again. Printing the index gives the indices of `self.vals`, ( 0, 1, 0, 1 ):

```
0
1
0
1
```

I would like output to be rather as such:

```
0
1
2
3
```

So, how can I get the inner loop index to not reset and keep an accumulating total of the loop runs? Thanks for your ideas : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumerate()` is simply counting each value in `self.vals`, so once all the items have been exhausted and the loop is run again, the count starts over.

To prevent it from being reset each time, the variable storing the index needs to defined outside the loop. Try setting `idx` to `0` outside the loop and incrementing by 1 inside the loop, like:

```
for n in df['col']:
    idx = 0
    for item in self.vals:
        print(idx)
        idx += 1
```